# How to reference the requiring file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to be able to give a required file the knowledge of the requiring, like so

```
#requiring file
require 'required_file', __FILE__
```

or

```
#required file
puts __REQUIRING_FILE__
```

is there a way to achieve that somehow ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can be aware of which file is requiring, but `Module` has callbacks `included` and `extended` so that you can react on another module trying to include it. Maybe you can refactor your concept to use this feature instead.

see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-included

Comment: That is in fact possible, but a little more complex: I can wrap my code in the required file in a module, then instead of merely requiring the file, I can also include the module defined in it, thus giving this module the knowledge of the class which included it.I was just wondering if this could be done more simply... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby also allows you to override the require method.

Here is an example where benchmarking was added to require https://gist.github.com/278994.
Then you can use Kernel.caller to get the name of the file that called the require method.